# My Gameobjects keep spawning right next to each other although I gave some offset

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, instantiation

I followed the script from one of Unity tutorials. I'm trying to adjust it to according to my requirements. Any help is appreciated. Below is an Image of how it appears. I've given an offset to  give some space while the object is being spawned but I feel like it doesn't work. Column min = 8, Column max = 20
[image]

```
 using System.Collections;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using UnityEngine;

    public class ObjectPooler : MonoBehaviour
    {

        private GameObject[] columnPool;
        public int columnSize =5;

        public GameObject columnPrefab;

        private Vector2 objectPoolPositionBeforeStart = new Vector2(12f, 0.42f); 

        public float timeSinceLastSpawned = 4f;
        public float spawnRate;
        public float columnMin, columnMax;
        private float spawnYPosition = 0.42f;
        private int currentColumn = 0;
        public float offset;
        // Use this for initialization

        void Start()
        {

            columnPool = new GameObject[columnSize]; 
            for (int i = 0; i < columnSize; i++)
            {
                columnPool[i] = Instantiate(columnPrefab, objectPoolPositionBeforeStart, Quaternion.identity);

            }
        }

        // Update is called once per frame
        void Update()
        {

                    timeSinceLastSpawned += Time.deltaTime;

          if (GameController.instance.gameOver == false && timeSinceLastSpawned >= spawnRate)
            {

                timeSinceLastSpawned = 0;
                float spawnXPosition = Random.Range(columnMin, columnMax) + offset;
                columnPool[currentColumn].transform.position = new Vector2(spawnXPosition, spawnYPosition);
                Debug.Log(spawnXPosition);
                currentColumn++;

                if(currentColumn >= columnSize)
                {
                    currentColumn = 0;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: How about applying a value to your `offset` variable?

Comment: It's already applied in the Inspector, a value of 5

Comment: you should easily be able to prove whether the offset is working or not by displaying the spawnxposition each time..   Of course at the start you start by making them all in the same place, you are only moving "current column" .. the pile will still be all in the original position...  until you do a full round of moving the items..  Why not put them out at the beginning

Comment: Put them out? As in remove the initial Object pool position?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Are you trying to instantiate the objects within a certain distance from each other?

Comment: Yes, without overlapping from one another and with enough room for the user to jump

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are definitely on the right track I believe. I'm guessing you want the columns to keep going further away, for every column that has previously been spawned (so that each new colum has a position relative to the previous column).

Currently, this is the code that determines the X position of a column.

```cs
float spawnXPosition = Random.Range(columnMin, columnMax) + offset;
```

This does not take other columns' positions into account. Perhaps you want to add the previous column's X position to this value?

```cs
float spawnXPosition = columnPool[currentColumn - 1].transform.position.x + Random.Range(columnMin, columnMax) + offset;
```

EDIT: Just make sure that `columnPool[currentColumn - 1]` doesn't go out of range! You don't want any original offset for the first column :)

Comment: As you mentioned, I keep getting an error after the first column is spawned, saying "IndexOutOfRangeException: Array index is out of range". Does this mean that I've to increase my current column index?

Comment: Since you don't to offset the first column relative to another column you can write an if-check to see if currentColumn != 0 and in that case add the column offset `columnPool[currentColumn - 1].transform.position.x` to `spawnXPosition`

Comment: `if (currentColumn != 0)
            {
                spawnXPosition = columnPool[currentColumn -1].transform.position.x + Random.Range(columnMin, columnMax) + offset;  
return;         
 }`
This seems to be working as I intended. Thank you